# creating the sql query for company supervisors

Tags: sql

I have four tables

```
create table emp (emp_ss int, emp_name nvarchar(20));

create table comp(comp_name nvarchar(20), comp_address nvarchar(20));

create table works (emp_ss int, comp_name nvarchar(20));

create table supervises (spv_ss int, emp_ss int );
```

Here SUPRVISER_SS and EMP_SS are subset of SS. Now I have to find:

1. the name of all the companies who have more than 4 supervisors

I have made a query for the above problem but not sure whether it is correct or not

```
SELECT COMP_NAME , COUNT(EMP_SS) FROM WORKS
WHERE EMP_SS IN (SELECT DISTINCT SPV_SS FROM supervises) 
GROUP BY COMP_NAME 
HAVING COUNT(EMP_SS) > 4;
```

2. the name of supervisors who have the largest number of employees
   but unable to get the required result of the above condition

   `SELECT SPV_SS, COUNT(*) max_ FROM supervises GROUP BY SPV_SS`

Comment: Homework, and you expect us to do it for you? If we did, you wouldn't learn much.

Comment: Make some effort. Show us sample table data and also the expected result - all as formatted text (no images). And show us _your_ query attempts. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Sorry but this is not just a free write-my-code, do-my-research or even do-my-thinking service. Please show your attempt at researching and solving the problem on your own first before asking for the (free, voluntary) time of others. We will _help_ you with your problem, not just replace you. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need to have a seperate table for supervisors unless they come with extra information that doesn't belong in the employee table, just add an extra field (foreign key) in Employee table that links to the primary key in the same table.
2. First question: select company just use a group by companyid clause and then check if the count of supervisors is larger than 4 for.
3. Second question: select count(empid) and supervisor, use group by supervisor clause and add order by clause on the count column
4. I explained the logic, as for the actual sql code, you're gonna have to figure that out yourself.

Comment: Please check I have added my code. For the problem 4, I only to get the row with max number of emp. How can I get that ?